# Find a,b,n so that (a^b)%n=x

Tags: c++, math, modular-arithmetic

Say I choose a value for x that can be between `0` and `2147483647`. (Int32.MaxValue)
I am trying to figure out how I can find values for `a,b,n` so that `(a^b)%n=x`
I already know that I can use ModPow to verify the values, but I don't know how I can find a fitting a,b and n.

```
#include <iostream>

/// Calculate (a^b)%n
/// \param a The base
/// \param b The exponent
/// \param n The modulo
/// \return (a^b)%n
int ModPow(int a, int b, int n) {
    long long x = 1, y = a;
    while (b > 0) {
        if (b % 2 == 1) {
            x = (x * y) % n; // multiplying with base
        }
        y = (y * y) % n; // squaring the base
        b /= 2;
    }
    return x % n;
}

int main() {

    int x = 1337;

    // How to find a,b,n so that (a^b)%n=x
    int a = ?;
    int b = ?;
    int n = ?;

    if(x == ModPow(a,b,n))
        printf("ok");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try a=x, b=1, n = x+1

Comment: How is the routine to choose between the infinitely many possible answers? Are you counting on the `int32` limitation to reduce the number of solutions much?

Comment: Brute force it. There is no other way.  That equation is at the root of PKI cryptography.  If you find a faster way you will get a prize.

Comment: @alterigel I want them to be 'somewhat random', aka `a != x`.

Comment: @RichardCritten ... and roll an entire industry to its knees in the process. =P. I put it on my bucket list to solve this as soon as I finish up that other task of [solving the halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) first.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Yes I want to limit the solutions to the first possible one.

Comment: What exactly is "the first possible one"? Alter igel already gave you one solution. What ordering of solutions are you using to choose the "first one"?

Comment: Any solution with `a != x` and `b != 1` will do, as long as there is one within int32 range.

Comment: I assume that `x` is the smallest solution between 0 and int32.maxvalue

Comment: @RichardCritten: Not really, since he gets to choose `a` and `n`.

Comment: @RichardCritten: So where do I go witj my (rewritten) answer to claim that price? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int n = 2147483647
int a = ModPow(x, 9241, n);
int b = 464773;
```

*n* = 2<sup>31</sup> − 1 is a prime number. So due to [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), *x*<sup>*n*</sup> mod *n* = *x* and *x*<sup>*n* − 1</sup> mod *n* = 1 (unless *x* = 0) so *x*<sup>2 *n* − 1</sup> mod *n* = *x*, too. 2 *n* − 1 = 9241 × 464773. So (*x*<sup>9241</sup> mod *n*)<sup>464773</sup> mod *n* = *x*. Note that you need *x* < *n* for this to work; *x* = 2147483647 cannot work if *n* is a 31 bit (i.e. signed) integer, too.

It took me a while to get here; for a long time I've had this answer messing about with [Carmichael numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number) and the [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) before I reached this easy solution. See [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50996097/revisions) for details.

Answer (score 1):

The [modulus operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty2ax9z9.aspx):

> Yields the remainder given by the following expression, where *e1* is the first operand and *e2* is the second: *e1 – (e1 / e2) * e2*

Therefor whatever the max value of `x` is, `n` must be larger. Since you're validating with `n` as an `int` and you're specifying the range: `0` and `numeric_limits<int>::max()` that **must** be an exclusive range, and for `n` to be an `int` the only possible value it can take is: `numeric_limits<int>::max()`.

With `n` forced our equation effectively becomes: *`a`<sup>`b`</sup> = `x`*.
<sub>We'll need to do a check here that `x` is not `1`, if it is *`b` = 0* and `a` can be anything in our legal range so we can arbitrarily pick *`a` = 2*. But baring this:</sub>

Our requirements are:

- *1 < `a` < `x`* and `a` is an `int`
- *1 < `b` < `x`* and `b` is an `int`

Given `x`, we can search for a combination of `a` and `b` that will fit as follows:

```
auto a = 0.0;
auto b = 1;

if(x == 1) {
    a = 2.0;
    b = 0;
} else {
    while((a = pow(x, 1.0 / ++b)) > 2.0) {
        double dummy;

        if(modf(a, &dummy) == 0.0) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

At this point, if *`a` >= 2.0* then there is a valid solution to the problem. Now as you as you are probably well aware, `pow` is a very expensive function so this will likely take a very long time to execute for larger values of `x`, I'd personally suggest finding an `a` and `b` for every number for which such a pair exists and storing them in a `map` and doing a lookup on that.
Anyway this is a demonstration of working code:

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](https://ideone.com/gzxkkT)